# R: transforming multiple sets to dataframes at once

Tags: r

I have 31 datasets corresponding to data about 31 teachers. I need to perform multiple transformations on all these datasets. One of them is transforming all of them into dataframes

```
 class(alexandre)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

As I said, I have 31 similar datasets, and  I need to transform all into dataframes. My code to do so has been

```
alexandre <- as.data.frame(alexandre)
adrian <- as.data.frame(adrian)
akemi <- as.data.frame(akemi)
arcanjo <- as.data.frame(arcanjo)
ana_barbara <- as.data.frame(ana_barbara)
brigida <- as.data.frame(brigida)
cleiton <- as.data.frame(cleiton)
daniela <- as.data.frame(daniela)
davi <- as.data.frame(davi)
eliezer <- as.data.frame(eliezer)
eduardo <- as.data.frame(eduardo)
eustaquio <- as.data.frame(eustaquio)
gilberto <- as.data.frame(gilberto)
gilmar <- as.data.frame(gilmar)
jorge <- as.data.frame(jorge)
juarez <- as.data.frame(juarez)
junior <- as.data.frame(junior)
```

... and add some rows to this code (31 lines of this). Obviously all these lines of code take too much space and there must be a faster(and more elegant) way to accomplish this. In fact, I tried this

```
teachers <- c(alexandre, akemi, adrian, brigida, davi, ...)

cnames <- function(x){
  colnames(x) <- c(1:18)
}

mapply(cnames, teachers)
```

Then I would do all the work with a few lines of code. And this method (form a vector containing all datasets, then use mapply on the vector) would make my work much easier because, as I said, I have to perform multiple transformation on all these datasets.

This code does not work, however. I get the following error:

```
 Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(1:18)) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

This error message is very unenlightening, I find. I have no idea what to do to to make the code work, which is obviously why I'm here. Any other methods to accomplish what I'm trying to do are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you are trying to accomplish/explain, I don't think the  function you wrote is correct

Comment: you could put at the datasets inside a list and and write a function to modify them as data frames all at once

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini I have 31 datasets with diferente column names. I want all of them to have the same colum names (numbers from 1 to 18). I know how to do this, but I want a faster way to do this - a way that doesn't involve 31 lines of code and copying and pasting words 31 times

Comment: I would store them in a list and follow below code, you can assign the names of the data frames to the list : names(l)<-c("df_1","df_2")
 and extract them with : list2env(l, envir = .GlobalEnv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a list to stock all your data.frame. It seems to work, but you need to find a way to extract all data.frame in the list after that.

```
df_1 <- data.frame(c(0, 1, 0), c(3, 4, 5))
df_2 <- data.frame(c(0, 1, 0), c(3, 4, 5))

l <- list(df_1, df_2)

lapply(l, function(x){
  colnames(x) <- 1:2
  return(x)
})
```

Comment: All these years and I had never used a list before in R.. haha. Thank you, it worked.

Comment: Yes you have! Data frames are lists but of a different class. Check `typeof(df)` and `class(df)`. Specifically, they are a list of equal length atomic vectors.

Answer (score 3):

As commented and often discussed in the R tag of SO, simply use a list to maintain all your individual, similarly structured data frames. Doing so allows you the following benefits:

1. Easily run operations consistently across all items using loops or apply family calls without separate naming assignments.
2. Organizes your environment and workspace with maintenance of **one** object with easy reference by number or name instead of 31 objects flooding your global environment.
3. Facilitates data frame migrations and handling with `rbind`, `cbind`, `split`, `by`, or other operations.

---

To create a list of all current data frames in global environment use `eapply` or `mget` filtering on data frame objects. Each returns a named list of data frames.

```
teachers_df_list <- Filter(is.data.frame, eapply(.GlobalEnv, identity))

teachers_df_list <- Filter(is.data.frame, mget(x=ls()))
```

Alternatively, source your data frames originally from file sources using list objects such as `list.files`:

```
teachers_df_list <- lapply(list.files(...), function(f) read.csv(f, ...))
```

You lose no functionality of data frame if stored inside a list.

```
head(teachers_df_list$alexandre)
tail(teachers_df_list$adrian)
summary(teachers_df_list$akemi)
...
```

Then run your needed operations with `lapply` like renaming columns with right-hand side function, `setNames`. Run other needed operations: `aggregate` or `lm`.

```
new_teachers_df_list <- lapply(teachers_df_list, 
                               function(df) setNames(df, paste0("col_", c(1:18)))

new_teachers_agg_list <- lapply(teachers_df_list, 
                                function(df) aggregate(col1 ~ col2, df, sum))

new_teachers_model_list <- lapply(teachers_df_list, 
                                  function(df) summary(lm(col1 ~ col2, df)))
```

Even compile all data frames into one master version using `do.call` + `rbind`:

```
# ADD A TEACHER INDICATOR COLUMN
new_teachers_df_list <- Map(function(df, n) transform(df, teacher=n),
                            new_teachers_df_list, names(new_teachers_df_list))

# BUILD SINGLE DF
teachers_df <- do.call(rbind, new_teachers_df_list)
```

Even `split` master version back into individual groupings if needed later on:

```
# SPLIT BACK TO LIST OF DFs
teachers_df_list <- split(teachers_df, teachers_df$teacher)
```